# Unable to Change Row Background Color in UltraGrid Using Infragistics in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, infragistics

I'm encountering an issue with setting the background color of a row in an UltraGrid using the Infragistics library in VB.NET. Here's the scenario:

I have a CellChange event handler that triggers when the value of a specific column ("Failed") is changed. Within the event handler, I'm trying to change the background color of the row based on the value of the "Failed" column.

I've implemented the following code:

```
Private Sub grdDetails_CellChange(sender As Object, e As CellEventArgs) Handles grdDetails.CellChange
    Try
        If e.Cell.Column.Key.ToLower() = "failed" Then
            Dim cell As UltraGridCell = e.Cell
            Dim checkedState As Boolean = Boolean.Parse(cell.Text)

            ' Access the row containing the cell
            Dim row As UltraGridRow = cell.Row

            If checkedState Then
                HighlightFailedRow(row)
            Else
                ResetRowAppearance(row)
            End If

            ' Update the row appearance immediately
            row.Refresh(RefreshRow.FireInitializeRow)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorHandler.EH.HandleException(ex, False)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub HighlightFailedRow(ByVal row As UltraGridRow)
    row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub

Private Sub ResetRowAppearance(ByVal row As UltraGridRow)
    row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

However, the background color of the row does not change as expected. I've verified that the event handler is triggered correctly, and the code execution reaches the HighlightFailedRow and ResetRowAppearance methods. I've also tried calling the Refresh method on the row after changing the appearance, but it doesn't have any effect.

I suspect that there might be some conflicting appearance settings or other factors preventing the background color from being applied. I have also set the ActiveAppearancesEnabled and SelectedAppearancesEnabled properties to False in the InitializeLayout event, as suggested in another solution, but it didn't resolve the issue.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to successfully change the background color of the row in the UltraGrid using the Infragistics library. Thank you in advance for your help.